# IE and firefox difference to keep a div to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have written this html, in Firefox, it displayed perfect what I want(the blue part is sticked to the bottom of the page). But in IE it didn't display right way, how can I modify the HTML so that the blue part can be at the left bottom of the page?

In addition, the red part is also not the same, can I modify HTML to make the red part the same in IE and firefox?

I am using IE8 and Firefox 3.6.12

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
        <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="main" style="">       
                        <div id="left_top" style="width:800px;float:left;background-color:pink;">left_top</div>
                        <div id="left_bottom" style="width:800px;float:left;background-color:blue;bottom:0px;position:fixed;">left_bottom</div>
                        <div id="right_all" style="width:200px;float:right;height:100%;background-color:red;">right_all</div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Add another question: Is it possible to use script to stick it to the bottom?

I tried to add a line in front of all code:

It works! But I don't know why.

Comment: You say you're "using IE8 and Firefox 3.6.12" but your sample code renders identically in those two browsers for me.

Comment: I retried it's not the same, big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 doesn't understand `position: fixed;`
here's an article explaining how to get around that: http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/

that will solve the problem with the bottom div.

Comment: Is it possible to use script to stick it to the bottom?

Comment: i don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean use a script to periodically place it to the bottom of the page, this can work around the issue.

Comment: i guess you could use javascript to do this, but in the article they offer a css only solution, which i believe is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Since the above solution would break all position:absolute on IE6 I suggest another method I developed some times ago

http://css.html.it/articoli/leggi/3074/position-fixed-performante-su-ie6/

http://www.html.it/articoli/3074/demo2.html (view source code demo here)

http://www.html.it/articoli/3074/demo.zip (demo download)